# Unzipping an archive with 7zip using a predefined lis of passwords

Tags: powershell, shell, 7zip

I am trying since hours to unpack a password-protected rar-archive.
The password is unknown and should be determined based on the contents of a JSON file.

```
$content = Get-Content "C:\JDownloader v2.0\cfg\org.jdownloader.extensions.extraction.ExtractionExtension.passwordlist.json"
$passwords = ConvertFrom-Json $content
$7ZipPath = '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"' 
$zipFile = Get-Clipboard
$output = Split-Path $zipFile

Write-Host (Get-Clipboard)

foreach ($password in $passwords) {
    7zip x -o$output -p$password $zipFile 
}
```

If I use the plain-text-password instead of the variable `$password`, everything is working as expected.

An example of the used JSON file is:

```json
 ["exclusivatom", "!§19!$20(18!&", "boar2009", "SE0283", "NIMA4K", "mirage"]
```

Comment: Please add an excerpt of the JSON file.

Comment: I have shortened it, but this is not the problem. ["exclusivatom", "!§19!$20(18!&", "boar2009", "SE0283", "NIMA4K","mirage"

Comment: Please [Format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189) your code because now it doesn't make much sense

Comment: I meant adding a sample of the JSON to the question would be helpful.

Comment: That is the pure json. There is no more to show. Sorry that i can't format it in comments

Comment: What I don't understand, is the principle. When i type in "-p%password%", then it will be unpacked. But if I use the variables instead with the dollar sign prefixed, it throws errors.

Comment: @DennisKassel: I tried to properly format the source code in your question as well as add the JSON example from your comment. Can you also specify what the error message is you are getting? Note, that you're not even using the `$7ZipPath` variable.